# Doctest expects nothing, but file.write() outputs something

Tags: python, doctest

I am running a simple doctest for a program, and part of the test is writing 1,000 blank lines to a text file.

```
>>> NUMLINES = 1000
>>> with open(file_path, "w") as f: f.write("blankline\\n"*NUMLINES)
>>> some_function(arg)
```

Doctest expects nothing, but writing to a file somehow produces the integer 10,000.

```
Failed example:
    with open(status_path,"w") as f: f.write("blankline\n"*NUMLINES)
Expected nothing
Got:
    10000
```

I have no idea where the 10,000 is coming from, and this isn't even something I am testing for. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

It seems like the value being returned is the sum of all characters written to the text file. `len("blankline\n") * NUMLINES` = 10,000

Comment: That's the value that `f.write()` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is wrong. [`f.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) returns something:

> `write(s)`
>
> Write the string *s* to the stream and return the number of characters written.

Note about inheritance: `open(mode="w")` returns an instance of `io.TextIOWrapper`, which inherits from `io.TextIOBase`, which provides the `write` method.